# How to get Joomla template style name?

Tags: templates, joomla

I have a joomla template that has two styles. The name of the template is **default**, and the styles are **cats** and **arts**. is there a way to return the name of the current style in use.

the code below only return the name of the template
`$template = $app->getTemplate();` 
if I do an `echo $template;` I get default. But what I would like to get, is whether I am using the style **cats** or the style **arts**

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The template object doesn't contain the name of the a templates style variations (as it's only really used for human administrators as a mnemonic).

The only way to tell which "style" is being used is to look at the `id` value of the template… this value will correspond to the one you see in the ID column of the "**Template Manager - Styles**" view.

```php
// Get the Joomla Application
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

// Get the template
$template = $app->getTemplate(true);

// Echo the ID
echo $template->id;
```

If you really need the "name" I think you're probably making a design mistake, having said that you could try loading the `style` model for the `$template->id` and retrieving it that way. e.g. something like this (*warning typed directly into SO, **NOT TESTED!***)

```
// Initialise some vars
$name = 'Style';
$prefix = 'TemplatesModel';
$config = array();

// Get the model
$templateStyleModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance($name, $prefix, $config);

// Load the specific style instance.
$templateStyleModel->load($template->id);

// Echo out the style name
echo $templateStyleModel->title;
```

Answer (score 0):

$params = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;

Use $params->get() to get the particular style's params.

Comment: $params->get() needs an argument. but I can't find any argument for the current style

Answer (score 0):

The solution look are looking for is:

```
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$template = $app->getTemplate(true);
$styleModel = new Joomla\Component\Templates\Administrator\Model\StyleModel();
$style = $styleModel->getItem($template->id);
$style->alias = Joomla\CMS\Filter\OutputFilter::stringURLSafe($style->title);
```